# Socket Server Keeps Emitting More Values than Expected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am using SocketIO in Node and React to display data in real-time from my backend server. I have a successful connection and I am getting a data stream. But I cannot understand why my server-side web socket is emitting more events than expected.

On the server side, the emission looks as follows:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('Emitting')
  setInterval(function() {
    socket.emit('Echo', global.value);
  }, 5000);
});
```

On the client side I have this:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80/', {transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']});

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to the websocket server');
});
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('Diconnected from the websocket server');
});

function App() {
  // const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  const [dataStream, setDataStream] = React.useState([
    { name: 0, x: 0, y: 0 },
    { name: 1, x: 1, y: 1 },
  ]);

  function appendData(dataPoint) {
    var prev = dataStream[dataStream.length - 1]
    if (dataStream.length > 10) {
      dataStream.reverse().pop()
      dataStream.reverse()
    }
    setDataStream(oldArray => [...oldArray, 
      { name: prev['name'] + 1, x: prev['x'] + 1, y: dataPoint} ]);
  }
    
  
  socket.once('Echo', (message) => {
    console.log("echo")
    appendData(message)
  });
```

I am using socket.once on the client side. According to my understanding of how this should work, I should only get a single update every 5 seconds given that I set the interval on my server side to be 5000 ms.

Looking at the console log in my browser I see this

[image]

It appears the socket.emit on the server side is streaming on faster intervals than expected. Any help would be appreciated

I tried switching from socket.on to socket.once but that did not work either.

Comment: On your server, what is the `io.on('connection', function(socket) { ... })` inside of.  Is it in some function that gets called more than once in the lifetime of the server?  Like in a route handler?  If so, then that would be your problem.  That needs to only ever run once for the entire lifetime of your server and should not be in a route handler that gets called many times.

Comment: Hey yeah, that is only getting executed once and I ensured that by looking at the logs of print statements where 'Emitting' is only shown once at the beginning. So I do not think that is the issue here :/